# How to execute a function just once in the void loop?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Simply, I want to make a counter to execute a subroutine if digital read gets a toggle value just thefirst time. But the result shows that the "aFunction" executes more than once (repeatedly).

Code:

```cpp
int lastState = 1;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    int currentState = digitalRead(D5);      
    if (currentState == 1) {
        if (currentState = !lastState) {
            aFunction();
        }
        lastState = !lastState;
    }
    Serial.println("Still running loop");     
    delay(2000);
}

void aFunction() {
    Serial.println("in a function");
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve in your problem?

Comment: your loop doesn't loop, I don't see how it would be executed more than once, unless it was called more than once.

Comment: @GradyPlayer in arduino ide, developers have added ways that `loop` function is exectued again and again by itself.

Comment: @Sma : thank you for respons. Yes i want to execute the subrutine just once, just in first time toogle. can you help? the result show execute repeatly..

Comment: @JakaSatria, in that case. Keep a global instance of ececution of that sub-routine. If that function is executed, then set it to 1, and keep looking for this variable in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to signal it's been run once:

```cpp
int lastState = 1;
int runOnce = 0;
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

    int currentState = digitalRead(D5);      
    if (currentState == 1) {

        if (currentState = !lastState) {
            if (runOnce == 0)
                aFunction();
        }
        lastState = !lastState;
    }

    Serial.println("Still running loop");     
    delay(2000);
}

void aFunction() {
    Serial.println("in a function");
    runOnce = 1;
}
```

So now your `aFunction()` sets the `runOnce` flag to 1 and it won't ever run again until the device is reset due to the `if` statement inside `loop()`.

Comment: @JakaSatria You're welcome!  If my answer helped you, an "Accept" and up upvote will help others facing a similar problem in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By keeping track of execution of function and checking it along with `currentState` variable will help you in achieving your goal.

Your code with this change will look like:

```cpp
bool executed = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    int currentState = digitalRead(D5);      
    if (currentState == 1 && executed == false) {
        executed = true;
        aFunction();
    }
    Serial.println("Still running loop");     
    delay(2000);
}

void aFunction() {
    Serial.println("in a function");
}
```

Comment: well done, it's work. thank you for your algorith, very thank :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result:

```cpp
bool executed = false;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    int currentState = digitalRead(D5);
    if (currentState == 1 && executed == false)
    {
        aFunction();

        executed = true;
    }
    if (currentState == 0 && executed == true)
    {
        aFunction();
        executed = false;
    }

    Serial.println("Still running loop");

    delay(2000);
}

void aFunction()
{
    Serial.println("in a function");
}
```

Comment: This will execute the function whenever `D5` changes, i don't think this is what original question was about.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies right here:

```
if (currentState == 1) {
    if (currentState = !lastState) {
        aFunction();
    }
    lastState = !lastState;
}
```

This will run indefinitely until currentState /= 1.  You are having problems because you're not exactly understanding how the code runs in runtime.  The computer is reading this repeatedly, and its reading if currentState==1 to execute the bracket.

The next issue is your nested if statement, it's not using a comparison operator.  You have an = sign, but you should have an == operator to compare currentstate to laststate.

Essentially, if you want it to run once, you need to make sure the function changes the variable currentState to something other than 1, then if you want this function to execute again at some other point during runtime, change currentState back 1 for this function to run again, where again it'll change currentState to something other than 1.

I suggest instead of using an integer for currentState to use a boolean true or false.  If true, execute, change to false at the end - since its changed to false it wont run again until its true again.